# Problema na desserialização de xml

Tags: c#, xml

Estou tentando converter o seguinte xml em objeto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas ele retorna as categorias vazias

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
Records records = new Records();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Records));
records = (Records)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlReportCategoria));
```

Records:

```
public class Records
{
    public List<Categoria> Categoria { get; set; }
}
```

Categoria:

```
public class Categoria
{
    public int Cat_ID { get; set; }
    public string Cat_Nome { get; set; }
    public List<SubCategoria> SubCategoria { get; set; }
}
```

SubCategoria:

```
public class SubCategoria
{
    public int CatRaiz_ID { get; set; }
    public int SubCat_ID { get; set; }
    public string SubCat_Nome { get; set; }
    public string SubCat_Keywords { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: e o erro qual que é?

Comment: Não há erro, ele apenas traz a lista de categorias Count = 0, adicionei uma imagem nova mostrando isso

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa especificar na sua classe qual elemento é a raiz da sua lista com o `XmlRoot`. O resto segue da forma que está.

Veja:

```
    public class Records
    {
        [XmlElement("Categoria")]
        public Categoria[] Categorias { get; set; }
    }


    [XmlRoot("Records")]
    public class Categoria
    {

        public int Cat_ID { get; set; }

        public string Cat_Nome { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("SubCategoria")]
        public List<SubCategoria> SubCategorias { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Categoria")]
    public class SubCategoria
    {
        public int CatRaiz_ID { get; set; }
        public int SubCat_ID { get; set; }
        public string SubCat_Nome { get; set; }
        public string SubCat_Keywords { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Funcionou dessa forma, obrigado!

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.